# Beethoven repeated sforzando

Tags: classical-music, beethoven

In some Beethoven works (e.g. 8th symphony - first movement) there are some parts with repeated sforzando. Are these intended as simple sforzando or sforzando within crescendo? Is there any historical source explaining this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually not sure by what do you mean by "repeated sforzando". I guess you are referring to passages that are repetitive and that have frequent sforzandi (for example, a sforzando each bar, etc.).

In any case, there are no fixed standard rules for these things. You have to see the context in which it happens; in general, any interpretation will make sense if it is coherent with the context. See where the passage goes, where does it come from, what is the role in the structure of the music, what is the harmony doing, the character of the music...

It is difficult to generalize. However, Beethoven's music is known for its insistence. How to "insist"? You have to see. Listen to good recordings and try yourself. If the passages in question are steady in rythm, harmony etc. there may be no need to do crescendo. Some people whant to always do crescendo/diminuendo; well, truth is that music can sometimes stay flat. For example, people who is stubborn do/say the same thing many times no matter what; translated to music, a "stubborn" expression will not do crescendo/diminuendo, but just repeat the same thing many times (until at the end it will explode, or maybe exhaust, who knows).

In addition, Beethoven wrote in a quite meticulous way, so chances are that there is no crescendo if he didn't wrote it. Again, this is not always the case and nothing can be generalized. At the end, to bring a score alive, many things that are not explicitly written need to happen.

Comment: I'm not sure where you learned that Beethoven was meticulous. Quite the opposite really; his scores are hardly legible and were completely impractical to use.  They had to be re-copied before they could even make the parts.  You also say it is difficult to generalize, and then spend an entire paragraph generalizing about LVB's music. The effect you describe is most notable a the *conclusion* of a movement or piece where the composer is intent on creating a sense of finality.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes I'm not sure if this was intended in the answer, but although you're definitely right that his handwriting and autograph organization were anything but meticulous, I think you could argue that the notation was. His dynamic indications are far more frequent than contemporaries, he's one of the first composers to explicitly mark una corda and sutain pedal markings, one of the first to use metronome markings, etc. The *style* isn't meticulous—I imagine his copyists *hated* him—but the musical indications are, at least for his time.

Comment: @PatMuchmore - couldn't agree more; my comments were made with respect to his style, and yes, certainly more meticulous in compositional instructions than his contemporaries.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes You are not sure where I learned that Beethoven was meticulous... Well, from manuscripts themselves. We are talking about written musical ideas, not about aesthetics of ink and paper. When a composer crosses out several versions of the very same rhythmic idea (e.g. see Appassionata) before he reaches one that he finds appropriate, he is meticulous (and perhaps obsessive to some extent?) in trying to write what he has in mind in an accurate way. Presentation has zero weight here.

Comment: @George - a musical idea, no matter how profound, is useless if poorly presented; just as it is also useless if poorly performed; just as it is also useless if it is poorly conceived.  Obsessive? Yes. I agree with "meticulous" in Pat's respect.  In your respect, "stubborn" seems to be more appropriate.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes So Beethoven's ideas are "useless" because their manuscripts are a mess? Well, how unlucky was Beethoven not having you to guide him!

Comment: @George - I'm going to ignore your immaturity here and focus on the larger point: that none of us can enjoy Beethoven's genius if we have no clear way of interpreting what he expresses. There is a similar story about Penderecki - an orchestra conductor at Curtis was rehearsing a Penderecki score; it was so poorly notated the piece could not be rehearsed. Frustrated, the conductor threw the score and said "He might be a genius, I don't know, I can't read his score!" We are lucky that other people took the time to make legible Beethoven's works, otherwise, we could not enjoy them as we do.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes Yes, I understand. But what does it have to do with what sforzandi mean in Beethoven?

Comment: @George - at this point it means very little; these comments have divulged considerably from the original topic.  Further discussion can be done in chat.

Comment: So I was right then: "presentation has zero weight here" (here = the question we are answering). No chat, thanks; it's been enough already.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yesterday a friend told me about a letter from Beethoven to Czerny where he actually makes some correlations between "insisted sforzatos" (e.g. the eight simphony 1 mvt before letter F) and a crescendo. I looked for this letter but didn't find it...

Answer (score 2):

The sforzando symbol, ***sfz***, is used to indicate a *single accented note*, much like the > mark, rather than a global change in dynamic level. As such, I don't see what the issue would be with repeating it.

As wikipedia [explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamics_%28music%29#Sudden_changes_and_accented_notes):

> Accented notes (notes to emphasize or play louder compared to surrounding notes) can be notated sforzando, sforzato, forzando or forzato (abbreviated sfz or fz) ("forcing" or "forced"). One particularly noteworthy use of forzando is in the second movement of Joseph Haydn's Surprise Symphony...
>
> Sforzando (or sforzato or forzando or forzato), indicates a forceful accent and is abbreviated as sf, sfz or fz.

So in the example below, the off-beat sixteenths are meant to be accented:

[image]

To the second part of your question, while I'm sure there are period descriptions of dynamic markings, I am not sure what they are.

Comment: Good answer here Caleb - and this is how Beethoven often used the sforzando as well; often replacing the accent mark with an "sf" or an "sfz".  In quick summation, a passage with repeated "sf" indicates a series of accented notes, not a global dynamic change.

Comment: Please note that _sforzando_ is not the same as an accent. Not for Beethoven, and not for any other composer. Notes with _sforzando_ are somehow accented, yes, but _sforzandi_ have connotations of wheight/pressure and, sometimes timing, that "regular" accents do not have. It is true, though, that _sforzandi_ don't refer to a global change of volume.

Comment: Side note: Wikipedia is not a good source of information (talking in general, not only for this particular case).

Comment: Haydn's Surprise Symphony - (Smile) (Sweet) (Sister) (Sadistic) **Surprise** (Service) **Symphony!**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the 8th symphony sforzando but the 5th symphony sforzando is pretty famous and pretty universally interpreted. Here is the Sforzando passage I am referring to(and I'm pretty sure the forte 1 measure early in the tympani is a typo from the publisher):

[image]

This is universally interpreted as having the first note of each bar accented while still doing a crescendo to forte. Can't say that sforzando after crescendo symbols always means accents in the crescendo but it does in this sforzando passage.